# Nuget System.Runtime.Numerics for .Net 4.0

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.0, dependencies, nuget

I'm trying to target my project at .Net 4.0.

I have a dependency on System.Numerics.dll which is available in the .net 4.0.

My goal is to have my assembly work on a wide range of targets and be distributable via nuget (which I'm fairly new to).

So I started replacing my regular assembly references with nuget packages, so far so good. When I get to the nuget package System.Runtime.Numerics is has a dependency on .net 4.5. So I can't use it if I want to target .net 4.0.

Is this an issue with the packaging of System.Runtime.Numerics or am I missing something.

Comment: You should not be doing this at all.  You already have the proper reference assemblies on your machine, put there by the VS installer.  Why these assemblies are available on Nuget isn't always very obvious, I think the vast majority of them get downloaded by projects that target .NETCore.  But specific to Numerics, the Nuget package has features that they considered too risky to include in framework 4.5.  Just tick the one you need to use from the Assemblies > Framework node in the dialog.

Comment: @Sprotty, any update for this question? Does the answer and the comment help you? If not, please let us to know.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an issue with the packaging of System.Runtime.Numerics or am I missing something.

Just as Hans Passant comment, "*But specific to Numerics, the Nuget package has features that they considered too risky to include in framework 4.5."*. You could get the framework support information from its referenced assembly:

[image]

So **the package System.Runtime.Numerics does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with .net 4.0 framework**.

**Update:**

The nuget package starts support at .net 4.5 framework, so we don not recommend to get this package to target .net 4.0. If you are interesting in creating a nuget package that targets a wide range of targets including .net 4.0, I would like provide you with a simple method to try it:

- Download the package `System.Runtime.Numerics` from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Numerics/4.3.0)
- Open it with [NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer).
- Add a new folder named `net40` and save it.

[image]

Then you add this package to the .net 4.0 framework project.

Comment: The point was that the System.Numerics.dll was introduced in .net 4.0 and doesn't seem to have changed significance in 4.5 so it seems odd that the nuget package starts support at 4.5.
It seems if your trying to write portable libraries Microsoft's not interested in anything below .Net 4.5. You answer pretty much just re-iterates whats in the question. What I'm trying to figure out is how to create a nuget package that targets a wide range of targets including .net 4.0. The closest I've come is https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.csproj

Comment: @Sprotty, Sorry for the late response. If you are trying to figure out is how to create a nuget package that targets a wide range of targets including .net 4.0, you can try the method in the update answer. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Leo, but from what I can see the method used by NewtonSoft is the approach that's taken in many high compatibility packages. I really don't like this as it complicates the build and means pretty much the whole .csproj file has to be changed by hand. But by using this approach targets that are compatible with the numeric nuget package can reference it and ones that aren't (i.e. .net 40) can reference the assembly directly. It also feels wrong re-packaging standard nuget's I can't point at specific reason, but it just has the feel of something that's going to cause problems down the line.